# Is every positive definite matrix also positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I am in trouble with the definitions of positive definite and positive  semidefinite matrices. By definition, does the following implication hold?

$$\mbox{positive definite} \implies \mbox{positive semidefinite}$$

I guess yes. Look at the following example. Let

$$A = \begin{vmatrix}
4 &-2& 0\\
-2& 4& -2\\
0&-2&4
\end{vmatrix}$$

It is a diagonally dominant matrix $(|a_{ii}|\geq \sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|$ for all $i$), so it is semidefinite positive. But, if I compute the eigenvalues, they are all strictly positive which implies actually that it is definite positive.

My question is: everytime I find that a matrix is semidefinite positive, thus I have to use another criterion in order to try to understand if it is "less" that semidefinite positive (i.e. definite positive)? Or am I wrong with something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, every positive definite matrix is also positive semidefinite.

Comment: like every positive number is non-negative

Comment: Thank you. So, everytime I find that a matrix is semidefinite positive, thus I have to use another criterion in order to try to understand if it is "less" that semidefinite positive (i.e. definite positive)?

Comment: I would say it's "more" than semidefinite positive (the set of semidefinite positive matrices is strictly contained in the set of definite positive matrices)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If positive definite implies positive semidefinite, I think that it should be the contrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive definite means "All eigenvalues are greater than zero."

Positive semi-definite means "All eigenvalues are greater than or equal to zero."

The first of these implies the second.

The second does not imply the first, as the all-zero matrix shows.

Comment: Clear, thank you. So, everytime I find that a matrix is semidefinite positive, thus I have to use another criterion in order to try to understand if it is "less" that semidefinite positive (i.e. definite positive)?

Comment: Actually, it's **more** than semi-definite -- it's all the way to **definite**. But yes, if you know only that a matrix is positive semi-definite, you need to do MORE to show that it's positive definite. (AFter all, sometimes it's NOT actually positive definite, e.g., my example of the zero-matrix.